# nth-child targeting all child elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following Demo:

```css
#parent:nth-child(1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div>first child</div>
    <div>second child</div>
    <div>third child</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I was expecting only the first child of the parent element to be blue, but instead they all are. Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

[The problem in your case is the way `:nth-child` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), basically you need to add it at the child/sibling level, not at the parent level (and since your `parent` has no different, your selector is basically just like `#parent`). With the selector in the way you have it, it taking it as if #parent is the first child you want to select, that's why it's all blue. Make a slight change and it'll be fine:

```css
#parent div:nth-child(1) {
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="parent">
         <div>first child</div>
         <div>second child</div>
         <div>third child</div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Also, as [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612146/george) just mentioned below, this will apply to any first div occurrence that's a descendant of `#parent`, in your case it makes no difference but it might with a different structure, so if you just want to limit it to direct descendants, you can use the more specific selector `#parent > div:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Might be worth noting that this would apply to *every* first occurring `div` that is a descendant of `#parent`, not just the immediate child.

Comment: @George good point!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have selected the parent in CSS, but did not select the element of its child name. Try this, I hope it will help you.

```css
#parent div:nth-child(1) {
  color: blue;
   }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div>first child</div>
    <div>second child</div>
    <div>third child</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just bcoz u have selected parent in css but not selected element of child name.
Try this one hope, will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome Mahesh! You should put your explanation *in* the body of the answer instead of adding a comment; you can still [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57679774/edit) the answer after you've posted it.